# Spring Boot Get Request: Failed to convert type java.lang.String to required type int

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot with the PagingAndSortingRepository.

My Post entity:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private int branch;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 240, max = 10000)
    private String article;

    @NotNull
    private String featuredImage;

    @NotNull
    private int authorId;

    private Date datePublished = new Date();
    private boolean commentsEnabled = true;
    private boolean enabled = false;
    private int views;
    private String snippetTitle;
    private String snippetDescription;

    @ManyToMany
    Set<Category> categories;

    @Transient
    private Set<Comment> comments;

    public Post(int branch , String article, String featuredImage, int authorId){
        this.branch = branch;
        this.article = article;
        this.featuredImage = featuredImage;
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }
```

My PostRepository:

```
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Integer> {
    @RestResource(path = "/byAuthorId")
    Page<Post> getPostsByAuthorId (Pageable pageable, int authorId);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Page<Post> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Optional<Post> findById(Integer integer);
}
```

I am trying to request the Posts by authorId with the getPostsByAuthorId method, with this URL: http://localhost:8081/posts/byAuthorId?page=1&size=1&authorId=1

Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "byAuthorId"]
```

- I already tried adding @RequestParam("authorId") int authorId.
- I already tried re-writing the method to check if Intellij still provides getPostsByAuthorId as method and not something like getPostsByAuthor_Id
- I haven't done anything with the controller regarding this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that autogenerated methods automatically get /search prefix.

Answer: http://localhost:8081/posts/search/byAuthorId?page=1&size=1&authorId=1